# Executing buffer content with Python to split window without freezing for long execution times

Tags: python, vim

Now I have `map <F5> :w<CR>:!python %<CR>` and if my script is doing long term work, vim freezes.

I want to direct output of script to the split window. Like `tail -f` but in vim.

Are there any plugin or function to do this job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really in the remit of Vim. See `:help design-not`, and take a look at [this thread](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/How-to-run-the-external-command-in-background-td1176383.html).

The best way is, as usual, the command line. However, if you really want to do this then you could use tmux and the vimux plugin to start off a python process in a tmux session.